# Geometry nodes. How to Separate mesh islands by the largest island?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to delete the smallest mesh islands to filter out the largest mesh island. All in geometry nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To separate the largest contiguous area of a mesh from the rest, you can use the following solution:

[image]

`Face Area` here returns the surface area of a face in the form of a float value, `Mesh Island` returns the respective index, and `Accumulate Field` accumulates the values in this case for each mesh island separately. Since I process these values here in the attribute domain *Faces*, the highest accumulated value can then be determined with the node `Attribute Statistic`.

This only needs to be compared with the accumulated values per Mesh Island and you have the necessary selection to delete the other faces.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a convoluted solution That I've just come up with.

Using the "Domain Size Node" "Compare Node" and a "Switch Node"

See Image for clarity.

[image]

Comment: Two possible drawbacks with this solution: it doesn't dynamically evaluate all islands, you have to add a new branch with its own index if there are more islands than available here; and second, it assumes "larger island=island with more vertices", which might not be the case if by "large" they mean face area.